# Disable "Type :quit<Enter> to exit Vim" message when pressing Ctrl+C

Tags: vim

I'm developing [a Vim plugin](https://github.com/someboddy/vim-erroneous) That needs to run a shell command(targeted for running compilers and build systems) and capture it's output. I also want to display the command's stdout and stderr as it runs, so I'm using Ruby for running the command(though I'm still displaying with Vim's `:echo` command, so I can set the highlight for stderr)

Anyways, I want to allow the user to cancel the command in the middle. Canceling a program is traditionally done with `Ctrl+C`, and Vim's allows the user to use `Ctrl+C` to cancel the current running vimscript by throwing `Vim:Interrupt`. I want to use Vim's `:sleep` command to allow the user to press `Ctrl+C` if they want to cancel the command they are running, catch `Vim:Interrupt`, and proceed accordingly.

My problem is that pressing `Ctrl+C` in Vim while not in insert mode causes Vim to display `Type :quit<Enter> to exit Vim` - and to erase whatever messages were echoed before. This is a problem for me, because I want to keep whatever output the command put in stdout and stderr before the user canceled it displayed(and maybe add a message that the command was canceled).

Is there any way to temporarily disable this message and keep whatever was echoed before the user pressed `Ctrl+C`?

Comment: Would temporarily mapping `<C-c>` to `<silent> <C-c>` help?

Comment: Just tried it and it works!. I was not aware of silent mapping. Please make an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prepend the left hand side of your mappings with `<silent>` to hide what they would normally output on the command line.

In this case, the following mapping should work (it seems to, here):

```
nnoremap <C-c> <silent> <C-c>
```